# Should History Educators reemphasize chronological aptitude?

Tags: education, history, philosophy-of-history

As a former History Instructor I was absolutely stunned by the widespread chronological ignorance displayed by many of my students. I was told by most of my students that they rarely learned about historical dates and time periods in their earlier years; they learned about The American Revolution, though the year 1776, was a mystery to them. And their chronological inaptitude went well beyond American History. For many of my students they were unable to understand the centuries old timeline of AD & BC...(or what is now commonly referred to as CE & BCE).  Most of my students were (initially) unable to distinguish 100 BC/BCE and 100 AD/CE....(for many of them, it may as well have been the same year, not realizing that there was a 200 year chronological difference!)

In the era of Political Correctness and "Wokeness", the field of History is becoming increasingly preoccupied with the enforcement of Radical Social Commentary and Righteously Activist curricula, rather than a discipline which teaches students to think and understand History as a temporal, chronological, epistemological and factual process. While History Teachers and Historians are certainly not morally passionless robots, at the same time, they should not be Agenda driven Moral Proselytizers.  The field of History, was the original, "just the facts" academic discipline whereby chronology, as well as a general familiarity with the evolution of historical time, were paramount.

Having said all this, should History Educators begin their own movement to reemphasize chronological aptitude?

Comment: WAS the field of History the original, "just the facts" academic discipline? We see today students not knowing X. I'm sure in times past, we would've seen them not knowing Y. Why is a lack of X-knowledge worse than a lack of Y-knowledge? Which events should we know the dates of? Don't we have to rank events in terms of their "importance" when choosing which to focus on in a given course? Aren't "agendas" going to play a role in decisions about this "importance"?

Comment: Thanks for the comment and question.

Comment: With regard to your first question, a student SHOULD be aware and familiar with the entire chronological dating process.  I am NOT advocating for a rote-like memory based chronological approach; rather, I am supporting the reteaching of a sequenced approach.  Chronology, is a sequential ordering of History that provides students with a linear understanding of past events and persons.  If, however, students have a haphazard understanding of and unfamiliarity with, historical time, then we should not be surprised by the widespread chronological inaptitude in our classrooms.

Comment: As for your second question.....No, we should not "rank events in terms of their importance when choosing which to focus on in a given course"  And here's why:  How do you define "importance"? Let's take my earlier example of The American Revolution.  My method of teaching The American Revolution has a traditional starting and ending point.  Would you support a method that selects or emphasizes Lexington and Concord, but excludes Yorktown? If we "rank events in terms of their importance", you are assuming that the Teacher has the knowledge and wisdom to deliberately and purposefully....

Comment: Yeah but you can interpret the entire American Revolution as an event, and then the question is, why teach students about that event instead of something else? Granted, in a specifically American history class, one would have reason to "start at the beginning" and proceed from there. However, how do we decide which events to teach after we've covered the American Revolution? There are so many of them. I, for one, think teaching Americans what the US did to Vietnam is as important as teaching Germans what the Nazis did to the Jews (and others). And yet...

Comment: "rank events", in terms of historical significance and meaning.  Such an approach may work well in a Senior level History seminar or Graduate level seminar, but not at the pre-Collegiate level or even at the Collegiate level-(with FEW exceptions).  The chronological approach, at an early age, is a sophisticated set of exercises which aims to  actually train the brain to think in terms of time.  If we discontinue the chronological approach or if we choose to "rank events according to so-called "importance", then we are likely to see evidence of widespread chronological inaptitude.

Comment: Yes but in any given chronological sequence, there are so many events that you're going to have to select just some to teach about in detail. It's unavoidable. Is chronological aptitude really that important when there are millions of other things in the world to learn? (Don't we have to identify chronological aptitude as an important capacity, in order to justify training people to acquire it?)

Comment: In terms of "agendas" and their "importance", yes, I actually think that the reteaching and reemphasis of chronologically based History has major "importance" in our greater Social Studies and Civically based Educational system.  The criticism that I have towards things, such as the Social Commentary approach towards Historical Education-(at the pre-Collegiate or pre Graduate levels), is that it is ahistorical and is not necessarily interested in understanding historical facts, but instead promoting an Activist based agenda...(and let the facts be damned).  History is NOT Social Commentary.

Comment: The field of History, is to teach students about the past...THAT'S IT.  Now, should one choose to insert a moral/social commentary WITHIN THE CONTEXT OF THE HISTORICAL SUBJECT, that is one thing.  However, to completely overhaul and transform the field of History into Moral/Social Commentary-(usually from an ultra-leftist perspective), is, in my opinion, robbing and depriving students of the rudiments of traditional historical education.

Comment: There's an old saying..."You have to learn how to walk before you run".  While you make a perfectly legitimate point about students learning about The Vietnam War-(which, incidentally, I have taught on more than one occasion...over the years), the Vietnam War occurred nearly 200 years AFTER The American Revolution.  If we, for example, take the unchronological approach (that you seem to be advocating for), what happened in the United States between the 1776 and 1964? Your approach would omit or circumvent important events, such as American Westward Expansionism, "The trail of tears", slavery..

Comment: This probably needs to be moved to chat...

Comment: and The Civil War.  However, my approach, while less detailed, would aim to encompass and discuss each of these events accordingly and with great importance, regardless of 'rank".  Sure, History Teachers cannot possibly teach everything-(that's self evident and you learn that on the FIRST DAY OF TEACHING!).  But, when you look at History as an unfolding continuous process, then we can see how History goes from A to B to C to D...and not jump from A to D or emphasize D and disregard A B and C.

Comment: I stand by my case....there is nothing more to discuss.  Many thanks for your comments.